# Does ktrain package combine input embedding with bert embedding when used for test classification?

Tags: keras, text-classification, embedding, bert-language-model

I am running the code given in the link below. What embeddings does the ktrain package of python use for bert text classification. I believe the code is using a pre-trained model of Bert. In that is it combining bert embeddings with input embeddings. Does the embeddings in the model take into account the input text given as well

Relevant part of Code

```py
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
x_train,  y_train), (x_test, y_test), preproc = text.texts_from_array(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,
                                                                       x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test,
                                                                       class_names=train_b.target_names,
                                                                       preprocess_mode='bert',
                                                                       ngram_range=1, 
                                                                       maxlen=350, 
                                                                       max_features=35000)

model = text.text_classifier('bert', train_data=(x_train, y_train), preproc=preproc)

learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=(x_train, y_train), batch_size=6)
```

https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/20newsgroups-BERT.ipynb